FastAPI return internal server error after deploy to serverless
Im new to python, and I am still learning how to use it.
So basically the issue now is I'm using uvicorn to run in local, it is working fine. 
But after i deployed to serverless, even tho it is successful but it still return me internal server error.

This is how my python folder looks like.

I also tried to debug it using serverless offline --debug and it is running perfectly fine too in it. But i have no idea why its not running properly in serverless production

Have you checked the log files for your serverless version?

Hi @MatsLindh, my serverless version is 4.4.11
Im still trying to find where to check the log in serverless

You'll have to check how your cloud provider makes logs from the nodes that runs your application available.
